# stk.nextToken() returns error "Unknown Source"

Tags: java, arrays, vector, matrix, 2d

I' re-doing an exam for practicing and i've almost completed it. The only problem i have is with this part:

```
               int z=0,x=0;

               String line="";

               RandomAccessFile read = new RandomAccessFile(s, "rw");


               while((read.readLine())!=null)
                   z++;

               read.seek(0);

               while(x<z){

                   line=read.readLine();

            StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");


            if(line.charAt(0)=='r'){
                nr=z;
                nc=stk.countTokens()-1;
                valori = new int[nr][nc];
                while(stk.hasMoreTokens()){
                stk.nextToken();
                for(int i=0; i<nr; i++)
                    for(int j=0; j<nc; j++)
                    valori[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());}
                }
            else if(line.charAt(0)=='c'){
                nr=stk.countTokens()-1;
                nc=z;
                valori = new int[nr][nc];
                while(stk.hasMoreTokens()){
                stk.nextToken();
                for(int i=0; i<nr; i++)
                    for(int j=0; j<nc-1; j++)
                    valori[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());}
                }x++;
```

Basically i have to read a file where i have the description of a matrix as follows:

```
c 0 1 0
c 0 0 1 
c 0 0 0
c 1 0 0
```

And the resulting matrix would be

```
|0|0|0|1|
|1|0|0|0|
|0|1|0|0|
```

After reading the file i have to build the matrix with a 2d int array, i used the same code from another exercise but when using stk.nextToken() i get java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)

I cannot find the error, 2d arrays are correctly initialized and filled.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error whilst using StringTokenizer on text file with multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856125/error-whilst-using-stringtokenizer-on-text-file-with-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 1):

The "Unknown Source" part of the exception is an effect of running your code through the jre instead of the JDK.  If you run with the JDK, your runtime environment will have access to the debug info and proper line numbers will be printed instead.

a quick look suggests that this section is in error:
      nr=stk.countTokens()-1;
      nc=z; //z == # of rows

```
  //first pass through = hasMoreTokens == true (a total of 4: C,0,1,0)
  while(stk.hasMoreTokens()){
            //first token - C
            stk.nextToken();
            //this will iterate 3 times
            for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++)
                //this, too, will iterate 4 times - a total of 12 times considering
                // the outer loop
                for(int j = 0; j < nc-1; j++)
                   // after 3 passes, this will throw the exception
                   valori[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());}
            }x++;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there are no more tokens in the StringTokenizer remaining, and you are asking for a one more token. "Unknown source" is not relevant to your problem - this just means you have no access to the source code of the Java system library but I doubt it will be helpful.

This happens because the line you read from the file contains less space delimited tokens than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because you are tokenizing one single line, and in the two for loops you are reading columns and rows.
Instead of using the StringTokenizer with while loops I would recommend to use the .split command:

```
int j=0;
// read all rows
while((read.readLine())!=null) {

    String line=read.readLine();
    String[] columns=line.split(" ");

    // read columns of each row
    int i=0;
    for (String column: columns) {
        if (!column.equals("c")) {
            valori[j][i] = Integer.parseInt(column);
        }
        i++;
    }

j++;
}
```

PS: Pseudo code above, untested.